# Why are there trailing slashes in NSURL initialized by initWithScheme ...?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

When using the `NSURL` initializer

```
initWithScheme:(NSString *) host:(NSString *) path:(NSString *)
```

iOS for some reason appends two extra trailing slashes if the path ends with a slash, unless it's only `@"/"`.

[image]

Does anyone know why this is, and if there's a way around it ***other than*** composing the url manually with something like

```
[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@://%@%@", scheme, host, path]];
```

---

**UPDATE:** Bug report has been sent to Apple.

Comment: Paths do not end with a "/".

Comment: as `path` pass `/some-path` and remove the `/` at the end

Comment: @luk2302 Having no slashes at all causes an NSInvalidArgumentException exception: "path is not absolute.". However, I do want one trailing slash because the web server expects that, otherwise it appends the slash with a 301 response.

Comment: @andrrs Yes, sorry, you should only remove the trailing `/`, not the leading -> see my answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File paths start with a "/" but do not end with a "/".

From: [Uniform resource locator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator):

The syntax is:

```
scheme://[user:password@]domain:port/path?query_string#fragment_id
```

Directory paths have a trailing "/" but it seems that `- initWithScheme:host:path:` does not support them and may just be an Apache convention.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'm still confused by the "///". Does that mean anything meaningful in URL terms? Otherwise it feels like the initializer should either accept the input or throw an NSInvalidArgumentException, not return some randomly modified URL. In my specific case the web server does a 301 to add the trailing slash so I'd rather not use this initializer at all, I'll go with some custom initializer instead, like [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@://%@%@", scheme, host, path]];

Comment: As far as I know that is a bug, submit a bug report to Apple: http://bugreport.apple.com

Answer (score 1):

Your path should not end with a `/`. The following will work:

```
[[NSURL alloc] initWithScheme:@"http" host:@"example.com" path:@"/hit"])
```

[image]